# ReacJS Delete elements from array using array key

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of values

```
[{"date":"2018-02-25 06:49:00.006","minute":"0","hour":"0"}
{"date":"2018-02-28 06:49:00.000","minute":"0","hour":"0"}
{"date":"2018-02-27 06:49:00.000","minute":"0","hour":"0"}]
```

When i'm trying to delete the element using the array key using the splice method as 
`this.state.dateArray.splice(index, key);` 
I'm able to delete all the elements except in the 0th key. How can i solve this?

Comment: The issue is solved. Thank you all.

Comment: You're confusing [`Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
with [`Array.prototype.slice(begin, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: That was my mistake @ArmanCharan. I just given as `this.state.dateArray.splice(key, 1);` and the issue is solved.

Comment: [Might also be best to `clone` `this.state` before `splicing` to avoid `mutating` your data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) `[...this.state.dateArray].splice(key, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep start position as `0`  which first param and second param is number of ele to be delete is `1`

```
this.state.dateArray.splice(0,1);
```

You can pass these ele as dyanmically.

From above script:

```
this.state.dateArray.splice(index, key);
```

Not sure,how the `key` here is generated but it should be number of ele to be delete and `index` should be start position.

Comment: `key` is the array key which should be deleted and i'm getting it dynamically on click of delete button

Comment: you can not give key from loop as number of ele to be delete as it will increment with every iteration.Should precisely defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the component which you are mapping through the array data is having the "key" attribute which takes unique value.